[Solved]Use ClosedXML to modify Crystal Report export stream - cannot SaveAs - get an exception
I use ClosedXML(0.102.3) to modify Crystal Report export Stream,
when  I use this code
ReportDocument crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();

crReportDocument.Load("D:\\Sample\\test.rpt");

ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = "connectionString"
};


foreach (ReportDocument subRpt in crReportDocument.Subreports)
{
    foreach (Table crTable in subRpt.Database.Tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo logInfo = new TableLogOnInfo
        {
            ConnectionInfo = connInfo
        };
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logInfo);
    }
}

foreach (Table crTable in crReportDocument.Database.Tables)
{
    TableLogOnInfo logInfo = new TableLogOnInfo
    {
        ConnectionInfo = connInfo
    };
    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logInfo);
}

var exportOptions = new ExportOptions
{
    ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.XLSXPagebased
};

var excelFormatOptions = new ExcelFormatOptions
{
    ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = false,
    ShowGridLines = true
};

exportOptions.ExportFormatOptions = excelFormatOptions;

var exportRequestContext = new ExportRequestContext
{
    ExportInfo = exportOptions
};

Stream excelStream = crReportDocument.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(exportRequestContext);

if (excelStream.CanSeek)
{
    excelStream.Position = 0;
}

//ClosedXML read begin
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(excelStream))
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
    var b = worksheet.Cell("A2");

    workbook.SaveAs(excelStream);   
}           

"workbook.SaveAs(outputStream);"  have exception
error message is
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Not implemented value!
Parameter name: value'
please help my i do not know how to solution this, thanks

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Also paste the full stack trace.
